# Retrieve Properties of Azure Table

Tags: azure

Is there any procedure to know the column names or Property Names for Azure Table Entity. I have each row to hold same type of data . I just need to know all property names at runtime for each entity.

-Mahender

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [DynamicTableEntity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/11/06/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-tables-deep-dive.aspx), [DictionaryTableEntity](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/dictionarytableentity-working-with-untyped-entities-in-the-table-storage-service/) or override the ReadEntity method:

```
    public override void ReadEntity(IDictionary<string, EntityProperty> properties, OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        // Store property names somewhere.
        base.ReadEntity(properties, operationContext);
    }
```

By overriding the ReadEntity method you can store all property names in a list for each entity.

**Note:** This answer assumes you're using the Table Storage v2.0 SDK

Comment: How is it possible with 1.7 SDK.?

Comment: By handling the ReadingEntity event on the context: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/28/reading-and-saving-table-storage-entities-without-knowing-the-schema-or-updating-tablestorageentity-schema-at-runtime.aspx